# openni_kinect on squeeze

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I installed ROS on squeeze via easy_install and it was done
successfully.
Then I tried to openni_kinect as described in
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect.
but as I performed
rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
then I got errors as below. Pls share if someone has idea what is the problem and how to make this works.

Thanks in advanced.

//////////////////

```
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are:
['openni_kinect']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/wandis/.ros/rosmake/
rosmake_output-20110506-180554
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openni_kinect'] to:
['nite', 'openni', 'openni_tracker', 'openni_camera']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing.
This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find rosdep nite-dev for package nite on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package nite on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package nite on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni_tracker on
OS:debian version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package openni_tracker on
OS:debian version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep nite-dev for package openni_tracker on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni_camera on
OS:debian version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep uuid for package openni_camera on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni_camera on OS:debian
version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package openni_camera on OS:debian
version:squeeze
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'nite-dev', u'openni-dev', u'ps-engine', u'openni-
dev', u'openni-dev', u'ps-engine', u'nite-dev', u'openni-dev',
u'uuid', u'libusb1.0', u'ps-engine'] could not be resolved
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
}}}

[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system
dependencies
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/
rospack
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/
rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nite
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> openni
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package
rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< openni [PASS] [ 2.33
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nite [PASS] [ 2.35
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cpp_common
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package
roslang
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cpp_common [PASS] [ 3.43
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_traits
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp [PASS] [ 3.40
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs [PASS] [ 4.11
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib [PASS] [ 4.25
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen [PASS] [ 0.03
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp_traits [PASS] [ 3.04
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime [PASS] [ 4.17
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean [PASS] [ 3.02
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph [PASS] [ 2.65
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmaster
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization [PASS] [ 2.92
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmaster [PASS] [ 2.66
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole [PASS] [ 4.49
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosnode
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit [PASS] [ 2.56
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tinyxml
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles [PASS] [ 3.13
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosnode [PASS] [ 3.15
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib [PASS] [ 0.03
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> yaml_cpp
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< yaml_cpp [PASS] [ 0.03
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cminpack
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cminpack [PASS] [ 0.04
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> flann
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< flann [PASS] [ 0.04
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 [PASS] [ 0.04
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tinyxml [PASS] [ 3.31
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 12.42
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond [PASS] [ 4.15
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy [PASS] [ 2.86
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib [PASS] [ 4.37
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp [PASS] [ 6.92
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout [PASS] [ 2.52
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch  No Makefile in package
roslaunch
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp [PASS] [ 2.54
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest [PASS] [ 2.23
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> topic_tools
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet [PASS] [ 5.10
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters
[ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package kdl written to:[ 4 Active
36/61 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/wandis/.ros/rosmake/
rosmake_output-20110506-180554/kdl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl [PASS] [ 3.07 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2
compiler warnings
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet [PASS] [ 3.68
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< topic_tools [PASS] [ 5.23
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbag
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters [PASS] [ 4.63
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbag [PASS] [ 3.84
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbagmigration
[ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbagmigration  No Makefile in package
rosbagmigration
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmsg
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmsg  No Makefile in package
rosmsg
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostopic
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools [PASS] [ 2.23
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostopic [PASS] [ 2.31
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice [PASS] [ 1.97
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf [PASS] [ 2.62
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs [PASS] [ 7.96
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure [PASS] [ 7.36
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs [PASS] [ 6.34
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> stereo_msgs
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers
[ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< stereo_msgs [PASS] [ 3.93
seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers [PASS] [ 4.08
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> camera_info_manager
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport [PASS] [ 4.68
seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_geometry
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< camera_info_manager [PASS] [ 3.56
seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge
[ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_geometry [PASS] [ 3.72
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf [PASS] [ 8.63
seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> openni_tracker
[ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge [PASS] [ 2.61
seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesl: 9.5 sec ] [ openni_track... [ 2 Active
57/61 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [rosbuild] Including /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/
clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/
clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/wandis/Program/
ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build
  cd build && make -l4
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openni_tracker.dir/src/
openni_tracker.o
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:8:22: error: XnOpenNI.h: No such file or
directory
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:9:24: error: XnCodecIDs.h: No such file or
directory
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:10:26: error: XnCppWrapper.h: No such file or
directory
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:14: error: 'xn' has not been declared
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or
type conversion before 'g_Context'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:15: error: 'xn' has not been declared
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or
type conversion before 'g_DepthGenerator'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:16: error: 'xn' has not been declared
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or
type conversion before 'g_UserGenerator'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:18: error: 'XnBool' does not name a type
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:19: error: 'XnChar' does not name a type
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:21: error: expected initializer before
'User_NewUser'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:30: error: expected initializer before
'User_LostUser'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:34: error: expected initializer before
'UserCalibration_CalibrationStart'
  /home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/
src/openni_tracker.cpp:38: error: expected initializer before
'UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd'
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/openni_tracker.dir/src/openni_tracker.o]
Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openni_tracker.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wandis/Program/ros_diamondback/
openni_kinect/openni_tracker/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package openni_tracker written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/wandis/.ros/rosmake/
rosmake_output-20110506-180554/openni_tracker/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< openni_tracker [FAIL] [ 4.89
seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package openni_tracker.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl [PASS] [ 11.70
seconds ]
[ rosmake ]
Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 59 packages with 1
failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to
directory
[ rosmake ] /home/wandis/.ros/rosmake/
rosmake_output-20110506-180554
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9910/openni_kinect-on-squeeze/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We don't have the openni drivers packaged as binary debs for squeeze.  The easiest way to get them is to check them out from the mercurial repo at https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers and make && make install from there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-23**:
Should this be added to the wiki?